# MYSQL selecting from two tables but the second table not always have relationship to the first

Tags: mysql, join

So I have two tables, one containing user info (`Users`), and the other containing info of which users not to show (`Settings`). So, I want to do a query that will show all the users in the `users` table except the ones listed in the `settings`. Thanks in advance.

**Users**

```
| id | name  |
===============
| 1  | adam  |  
| 2  | alex  |  
| 3  | andrew|
```

**Settings**

```
| id | name | value | user_id |
===============================  
| 1  | hide | 1     | 1       |
```

I want the results to be :

```
| id | name  | 
==============
| 1  | alex  |  
| 2  | andrew|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM settings WHERE name="hide");
```

would get only the users from the users table which are not in the settings table where the setting name equals "hide"

Answer (score 2):

To get list of something present in one table, but not in another (related) one, you can either use the famouse LEFT JOIN-NULL combo:

```
   SELECT u.id, u.name
     FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN settings AS s
       ON s.user_id = u.id
    WHERE s.user_id IS NULL
```

... or NOT IN clause on dependent sub-query:

```
   SELECT u.id, u.name
     FROM users AS u
    WHERE u.id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM settings)
```

I usually use the first one, but according to [this article](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/), there should not be any significant speed difference between those. Anyway, I'd suggest benchmarking them on your specific DB instance, then choosing the best one.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT * FROM settings)`

Comment: Why are you getting all the columns in your subquery rather than `user_id`?

Comment: its a general select statement, he can tweak it and specify how he would like to filter his results

Comment: If you're selecting from any of the other columns for a more populated table, you're going to get an incorrect result. The result that he needs is for it to be filtered on `user_id`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM settings WHERE user_id='1');`